# Site not displaying at all in FF but works just fine in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

In the company I work for, there are three servers; Dev, QA and Prod.

The Dev site I am working on is shown perfectly in all three browsers (IE 11, FF 29, Chrome 34). The QA site is not.

It loads in IE and Chrome, but in FF I get this error:

*"Page Unavailable - The page you requested is temporarily unavailable"*

Which is the default error for my companys website. I tried re-installing FF and clearing the cache, but nothing seems to work.

In the html of the index page, I am using the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

to load the default content for IE. I have created another page with no meta tag, no javascript, and it still does not load in FF.

I tried to change the settings on FF using this [article,](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/953639) but it did not work.

A co-worker is also having the same issue but in her case, QA is not loading in IE but works perfectly in FF and Chrome.

Has anybody had the same issue before? Know any fix? Do you think it has to do with the browser itself? Or with the markup?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you checked if FF can reach other websites on the server in question?

Comment: can we see a link to the page in question ?

Comment: @A.Wolff NO error at all in console...

Comment: @dSquared yes other sites can be accessed.

Comment: It could be a network issue and IE has it cached somehow that's why you see it there and not in FF ? are you sure QA server is online ? try to `cURL` it and see if it works as expected

Comment: What is the status code of that default error page? Is this page shown for a specific status or all errors / 404s?

Comment: I cleared out the cache for IE and now the page for QA does not load..

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing  wrong with FF
This is something with server configuration (probably it serves pages differently depending on user agent, or you are getting pages from different servers because of different network/proxy settings in different browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Verify Firefox's proxy settings.  I experienced on some systems that some versions of firefox would autodetect incorrect proxy settings and as a result would fail to load any page.  When I configured it to not use a proxy it then worked as expected.